# Iphone flagging url as insecure

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, https, web

I'm debugging a site using an iphone with ios 6.. Using the inspector from the iphone on the mac while visiting a site I get:

`Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.photorank.me” which could put your confidential information at risk.`

When I go to the same site on a mac using ffox/chrome/safari that issue does not exists.

The URL with the issue is https://www.photorank.me/static/js/olapic/widgets/ecommerce.js

It seems that the certificate is invalid for some reason but the only device saying so is the iphone and ipad..

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that the certificate doesn't how ownership information?

Answer (score 0):

It's not trusted, [see this](http://www.digicert.com/help/) or [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html). OSX might have wider root certificates base than iOs devices or simulator.